# Use REST API support in local development environment for Hyperledger Fabric V1.0

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have setup a **HyperLedger Fabric V1.0 network** with **4 organisations** ***each having 1 peer*** by following the steps [Building Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html).

> Now I have
>
> 1. **org1.example.com** - with *peer*: ***peer0.org1.example.com*** and *msp*: ***Org1MSP***
> 2. **org2.example.com** - with *peer*: ***peer0.org2.example.com*** and *msp*: ***Org2MSP***
> 3. **org3.example.com** - with *peer*: ***peer0.org3.example.com*** and *msp*: ***Org3MSP***
> 4. **org4.example.com** - with *peer*: ***peer0.org4.example.com*** and *msp*: ***Org4MSP***

And now I can install the chaincode to peers and instantiate the chaincode on the channel. I can also able to invoke and query chain code by using the commands mentioned [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) like

> ***Invoke***: 
> peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
>   -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'
>
> ***Query***: 
> peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'

I was previously using Hyperledger Fabric V0.6 service provided by [IBM Bluemix](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain) and my java applications were invoking the chain code through the **Rest API**.

How can I use the ***Rest API*** here in this *local network* setup using ***docker image***?, then my **java applications** can interact with my chaincode. 

Since I am not so familiar with this *local network* setup, please suggest me how can I make it work.

> **Note:**
>   
>  I am using **Windows 7 machin**e and network is setup by running
>   the commands in ***docker quick start terminal***

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no REST API in Hyperledger Fabric v.1.0.0, however there is Java SDK which could be used to interact with peers. You can setup your java project with following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>fabric-sdk-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can use SDK APIs to invoke/query your chaincodes:

Get instance of HF client

```
    final HFClient client = HFClient.createNewInstance();
```

Setup crypto materials for client

```
    // Set default crypto suite for HF client
    client.setCryptoSuite(CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite());

    client.setUserContext(new User() {

        public String getName() {
            return "testUser";
        }

        public Set<String> getRoles() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getAccount() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getAffiliation() {
            return null;
        }

        public Enrollment getEnrollment() {
            return new Enrollment() {
                public PrivateKey getKey() {
                    // Load your private key
                }

                public String getCert() {
                    // Read client certificate
                }
            };
        }

        public String getMspId() {
            return "Org1MSP";
        }
    });
```

Now channel configuration:

```
    final Channel channel = client.newChannel("mychannel");

    channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer0", "grpc://localhost:7050"));
    channel.addPeer(client.newPeer("peer0", "grpc://localhost:7051"));

    channel.initialize();
```

Create transaction proposal:

```
    final TransactionProposalRequest proposalRequest = client.newTransactionProposalRequest();

    final ChaincodeID chaincodeID = ChaincodeID.newBuilder()
            .setName("myCC")
            .setVersion("1.0")
            .setPath("github.com/yourpackage/chaincode/")
            .build();

    proposalRequest.setChaincodeID(chaincodeID);
    proposalRequest.setFcn("fcn");
    proposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
    proposalRequest.setArgs(new String[]{"arg1", "arg2"});
```

Send proposal

```
    final Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channel.sendTransactionProposal(proposalRequest);

    CompletableFuture<BlockEvent.TransactionEvent> txFuture = channel.sendTransaction(responses, client.getUserContext());

    BlockEvent.TransactionEvent event = txFuture.get();

    System.out.println(event.toString());
```

Comment: Oh.. thats cool :) In my case, when I tried the fabcar sample with node.js sdk, grpc://localhost:7050 was not working and after replacing it with virtual machine IP grpc://192.168.99.100:7051(in my machine) it worked. Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Comment: Hi can you just check what went wrong with my code that I have posted.

Comment: Can you open s separate question for that?

Comment: Original question asks about REST while updated question has nothing to do with REST API and therefore misleading.

Comment: I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880873/issue-while-using-fabric-client-java-sdk-since-there-is-no-rest-api-support-in