# Issue while using fabric client java sdk (since there is no Rest API support) in local development environment for Hyperledher Fabric V1.0

Tags: java, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have done the following as per the suggestion that I have got from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774774/use-rest-api-support-in-local-development-environment-for-hyperledher-fabric-v1) to communicate with locally running Hyperledger Fabric V1.0 network from java application. But I am getting the exceptions given below and unable to sort it out why it is happening.

```
public class Test {

    final HFClient client = HFClient.createNewInstance();
    Channel channel;
    TransactionProposalRequest proposalRequest;

    void setupCryptoMaterialsForClient() throws CryptoException, InvalidArgumentException{
        // Set default crypto suite for HF client

        client.setCryptoSuite(CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite());

        client.setUserContext(new User() {

            public String getName() {
                return "PeerAdmin";
            }

            public Set<String> getRoles() {
                return null;
            }

            public String getAccount() {
                return null;
            }

            public String getAffiliation() {
                return null;
            }

            public Enrollment getEnrollment() {
                return new Enrollment() {
                    public PrivateKey getKey() {
                        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
                        try {
                            File privateKeyFile = findFileSk("C:/Users/Public/HyperledgerFabricV1/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore");
                            privateKey = getPrivateKeyFromBytes(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile)));
                        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return privateKey;
                    }

                    public String getCert() {

                        String certificate = null;
                        try {
                            File certificateFile = new File("C:/Users/Public/HyperledgerFabricV1/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem");
                            certificate = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(certificateFile)), "UTF-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return certificate;
                    }
                };
            }

            public String getMspId() {
                return "Org1MSP";
            }
        });
    }

    static File findFileSk(String directorys) {

        File directory = new File(directorys);

        File[] matches = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith("_sk"));

        if (null == matches) {
            throw new RuntimeException(format("Matches returned null does %s directory exist?", directory.getAbsoluteFile().getName()));
        }

        if (matches.length != 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException(format("Expected in %s only 1 sk file but found %d", directory.getAbsoluteFile().getName(), matches.length));
        }

        return matches[0];
    }

    static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromBytes(byte[] data) throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        final Reader pemReader = new StringReader(new String(data));

        final PrivateKeyInfo pemPair;
        try (PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(pemReader)) {
            pemPair = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
        }

        PrivateKey privateKey = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).getPrivateKey(pemPair);

        return privateKey;
    }


void createChannel() throws InvalidArgumentException, TransactionException{
    channel = client.newChannel("mychannel");
    Properties ordererProperties = new Properties();
    ordererProperties.setProperty("pemFile", "C:/Users/Public/HyperledgerFabricV1/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt");
    ordererProperties.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true"); //testing environment only NOT FOR PRODUCTION!
    ordererProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "orderer.example.com");
    ordererProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
    ordererProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
    ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTime", new Object[] {5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES});
    ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTimeout", new Object[] {8L, TimeUnit.SECONDS});
    channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpc://192.168.99.100:7050",ordererProperties));

    Properties peerProperties = new Properties();
    peerProperties.setProperty("pemFile", "C:/Users/Public/HyperledgerFabricV1/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt"); 
    peerProperties.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true"); //testing environment only NOT FOR PRODUCTION!    
    peerProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "peer0.org1.example.com");
    peerProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
    peerProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
    peerProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 9000000);
    channel.addPeer(client.newPeer("peer0.org1.example.com", "grpc://192.168.99.100:7051",peerProperties));
    channel.initialize();
}

    void creteTransactionalProposal(){
        proposalRequest = client.newTransactionProposalRequest();

        final ChaincodeID chaincodeID = ChaincodeID.newBuilder()
                .setName("asset")
                .setVersion("1.0")
                .setPath("github.com/mygitId/myFabricRepo/assetChainCode")
                .build();

        proposalRequest.setChaincodeID(chaincodeID);
        proposalRequest.setFcn("createAsset");
        //proposalRequest.setFcn("init");
        proposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
        proposalRequest.setArgs(new String[]{"ORG1", "{\"assetKey\":\"a1\",\"assetName\":\"aname1\",\"assetType\":\"atype1\",\"slNo\":\"slno1\",\"orderDate\":\"19-05-2017\"}"});
    }

    void sendProposal() throws ProposalException, InvalidArgumentException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        final Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channel.sendTransactionProposal(proposalRequest);
        CompletableFuture<BlockEvent.TransactionEvent> txFuture = channel.sendTransaction(responses, client.getUserContext());
        BlockEvent.TransactionEvent event = txFuture.get();
        System.out.println(event.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setupCryptoMaterialsForClient();
        t.createChannel();
        t.creteTransactionalProposal();
        t.sendProposal();
    }
}
```

And this is my `docker ps`
[image]

And by running the code in eclipse java project getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: INTERNAL
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendDeliver(OrdererClient.java:286)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendDeliver(Orderer.java:165)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLatestBlock(Channel.java:1074)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigurationBlock(Channel.java:898)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:826)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:526)
    at com.ibs.blockchain.client.test.Test.createChannel(Test.java:151)
    at com.ibs.blockchain.client.test.Test.main(Test.java:179)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:540)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:392)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:76)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:512)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:429)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:544)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:52)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 1503010002
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:85)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.verifyFirstFrameIsSettings(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:309)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:217)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:401)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:565)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:479)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

Someone please look into the code help me to find where I am doing wrong.

The ip `192.168.99.100` given is the virtual machine ip

***Note:***
I am using **Windows 7** with [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) by following the steps [Building Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) and running my java application through eclipse.

**Update:**

Updated the function `createChannel` by adding TLS as per @Gari Singh's answer by referring [fabric-sdk-java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) source. But now also same error.
**Update:**

This docker quick start terminal console after running the java client, seems no logs coming
[image]

Comment: Could you send the logs that you get in the Orderer?! Have you got any log in the Peer?! Could you show all of them?

Comment: attached docker terminal, but there it showing no logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you created the crypto material?! I'm not asking about the tool that you used, my question is more related to the Common Name that you defined for the certificates. The CN of the certificates have to be the same to the host to which you are connecting.

If I were you, I'd create the crypto material with the **cryptogen** tool. Then, I'd change the URL for the call. I understand that you are in a localhost, so instead of 192.168.99.100, could you try to call orderer.example.com.

On the other hand, I think that you don't have to execute the `createchannel`, because you have create it before.

Answer (score 2):

If you used the  **first-network** sample, it has TLS enabled and in your code above you are not using TLS.  So my best guess is that the error is caused by not using TLS in your client.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Then what can I don now to make it work? Since I don't have deeper knowledge in this, can you just give me some more hints. Everything except this part is working fine for me :(,  if it is working I can continue my work.

Comment: Yes. I am using first-network and making it up using `./byfn.sh -m up`

Comment: Hi.. I have added TLS by referring fabric-sdk-java source file, and now also same error. Code is updated in the post. Is it correct or anything to add/change more on this?

Comment: Try using "grpcs://" in your URLs -

channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpcs://192.168.99.100:7050",ordererProperties));


channel.addPeer(client.newPeer("peer0.org1.example.com", "grpcs://192.168.99.100:7051",peerProperties));

Comment: Yes.. That makes some difference but a new error coming
`2017-08-25 17:33:28,423 grpc-default-executor-0 WARN  OrdererClient:263 - onCompleted
2017-08-25 17:33:28,424 main ERROR Channel:934 - Bad newest block expected status 200  got  404, Channel mychannel
org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Bad newest block expected status 200  got  404, Channel mychannel`

Comment: It is not creating the channel, but if we create and instantiate the channel through `CLI`, then it is initializing the channel, but there after it is waiting indefinitely at the line `BlockEvent.TransactionEvent event = txFuture.get();`
without showing any errors, but nothing is happening.