# Failed getting affiliation at the time of user registration using Fabric Client Java SDK V1.0.1

Tags: java, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have a **Hyperledger Fabric V1.0 networ**k setup using [Build Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html).

I have made the network up by running the command **`./byfn.sh -m up`**.
Now all the *Peers, Orderers and CAs*(***configured in docker-compose-e2e.yaml***) are up and running.

This is my `docker ps`
[image]

And I am trying to connect to this network using [fabric-sdk-java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java).

But when doing user registration using the following code

```
HFCAClient ca = sampleOrg.getCAClient();
final String orgName = sampleOrg.getName();
final String mspid = sampleOrg.getMSPID();
ca.setCryptoSuite(CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite());
SampleUser admin = sampleStore.getMember("ädmin", orgName);
if (!admin.isEnrolled()) {  //Preregistered admin only needs to be enrolled with Fabric caClient.
    admin.setEnrollment(ca.enroll(admin.getName(), "adminpw"));
    admin.setMspId(mspid);
}   

sampleOrg.setAdmin(admin); // The admin of this org --
SampleUser user = sampleStore.getMember("user", sampleOrg.getName());
if (!user.isRegistered()) {  // users need to be registered AND enrolled
    RegistrationRequest rr = new RegistrationRequest(user.getName(), "org1.department1");
    user.setEnrollmentSecret(ca.register(rr, admin// here comes the error
}
```

I am getting the error

```
2017-08-29 07:44:01,132 main ERROR HFCAClient:237 - com.test.blockchain.client.test.SampleUser@73846619
org.hyperledger.fabric_ca.sdk.exception.RegistrationException: Error while registering the user com.test.blockchain.client.test.SampleUser@73846619 url: https://192.168.99.100:7054  POST request to https://192.168.99.100:7054/api/v1/register failed request body {"id":"user1","type":"user","max_enrollments":0,"affiliation":"org1.department1","attrs":[]} with status code: 500. Response: {"success":false,"result":null,"errors":[{"code":0,"message":"Failed getting affiliation 'org1.department1': sql: no rows in result set"}],"messages":[]}
 
    at org.hyperledger.fabric_ca.sdk.HFCAClient.register(HFCAClient.java:236)
    at com.test.blockchain.client.test.Test.setup(Test.java:164)
    at com.test.blockchain.client.test.Test.main(Test.java:982)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: POST request to https://192.168.99.100:7054/api/v1/register failed request body {"id":"user1","type":"user","max_enrollments":0,"affiliation":"org1.department1","attrs":[]} with status code: 500. Response: {"success":false,"result":null,"errors":[{"code":0,"message":"Failed getting affiliation 'org1.department1': sql: no rows in result set"}],"messages":[]}

    at org.hyperledger.fabric_ca.sdk.HFCAClient.httpPost(HFCAClient.java:609)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric_ca.sdk.HFCAClient.register(HFCAClient.java:227)
    ... 2 more
```

I am referring the codes shown in the unit test class [End2endIT.java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/End2endIT.java)

Someone please share your knowledge to find out where I am doing wrong.

Also I am not sure where it is configuring `"affiliation":"org1.department1"`. 
Do I need to add anything in my ***`.yaml`*** file?

Comment: I'm having the same issue... did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

These are the affiliation which are bootstrapped for the any CA containers

```
> affiliations:   
>   org1:
>       - department1
>       - department2    
>   org2:
>       - department1
```

But there function though which you can add New affiliation based on your organization

```
await caClient.newAffiliationService().create({ "name": "AFFILIATION_NAME }, adminObj)
```

Comment: thanks, it really helped me i forgot to edit my affilations section in fabric-ca-server-config.yaml

Comment: Can u please explain what is meant by affiliation here?

Answer (score 1):

You configure the affiliation when you create the crypto material. In your case when you generate the **`./byfn.sh -m up`** command. You have created your keys (your certificates) when you executed the ./byfn.sh -m up, so you don't need to call the CA to register any user.

Also, your error code is the 500, so the cause of your error should be other. Could you try to invoke the chaincode?

Have you changed something in the *crypto-config.yaml* file? And in the *docker-compose-e2e.yaml* file?

Comment: Yes, I have just changed the 2 organizations each having 2 peers model to 4 organisations each having 1 peer model. I did nothing other than that. Also how can we configure this affiliation  crypto-config.yaml, I didn't find its syntax.

Comment: In the crypto-config.yaml file you have to set the 'Template: Count: ' to 1, instead of 2, for every organization.

Comment: Yes, that I have done and my network is working fine as shown in `docker ps`. Here my problem is I don't know howto configure this `affiliation` which needs to be passed for user registration.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Can you just see my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880873/issue-while-using-fabric-client-java-sdk-since-there-is-no-rest-api-support-in, this is how I have started, but that also not working. So because of not much information available I just tried to do as in fabric-sdk-java junit test class mentioned in this post, then I reached at this current issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the error you are getting for org1.department1. But even I had faced this similar issue while creating new org3. I was getting error  **Failed getting affiliation 'org3.department1': : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set**.

To answer where the setting of the Affiliation happens.
It is bootstrapped, which is defined the file **/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml** of **CA Docker container**

```
affiliations:
   org1:
      - department1
      - department2
   org2:
      - department1
```

Link to the file : http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serverconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

In line:

```
SampleUser admin = sampleStore.getMember("ädmin", orgName);
```

you may have to replace the **ä** in "ädmin".

Comment: Please expand on this to make it a full answer.